# Extract text from document in a SharePoint 2013 library

Tags: development, document, client-object-model

I would like to extract the text from documents stored in a SharePoint 2013 online Document Library.

I have the document loaded using:

```
ClientResult<Stream> data = file.OpenBinaryStream();
```

Ideally I would like to use iFilters to extract the text to a string (I would prefer this method as OpenXML will limit the documents types and versions).

I know this is a big ask but could anyone provide guidance on passing the data through an iFilter to produce a string that contains it's plain text.

[This Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13391/Using-IFilter-in-C) has an example of exactly what I would like to achieve but it expects a local file - could anyone advise on how a SharePoint file could be passed into this example.

I am using C# CSOM and would really appreciate any guidance.

Comment: I have used http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13391/Using-IFilter-in-C which is great for files on a local machine but I am stuck on how I could pass a SharePoint file into this example.  Beers are on me for anyone who can help!  Thanks again.

Comment: What type of documents are present? Do you wish to extract document text or document properties?

Comment: Simple awnser: why don't you save the binary stream to a temp folder?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access document properties metadata then you can use Quick Parts.

In order to access the document text, you will have to use SharePoint and OpenXML to read the document text. Here is an article.. Here are some articles that will give you way ahead with examples.

[SharePoint and Open XML](http://sharepointblog.acando.com/2012/11/08/sharepoint-and-open-xml/)

[Modifying an Open XML Document in a SharePoint Document Library](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2010/03/24/modifying-an-open-xml-document-in-a-sharepoint-document-library.aspx)

[Modifying Open XML Documents using the SharePoint Object Model](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/12/12/modifying-open-xml-documents-using-the-sharepoint-object-model.aspx)

Comment: Hi - thanks for your reply.  As I mentioned I would like to use iFilters as that means I can get text from all versions of Office documents and also PDFs.

Comment: Did you check this link, about pdfs:- http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45846/reading-contents-inside-pdf-file